# MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime returns null in work thread

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I use MediaMetadataRetriever to get a video frame from a mp4 file in raw, and the codes are:

```
final MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(coverParams.mContext, coverParams.mUri);
final Bitmap bmp = mmr.getFrameAtTime(coverParams.mPositon,OPTION_CLOSEST);
mmr.release();
```

if I run these codes in main thread, they works well and I can get a not null bmp. However, if run them in AsyncTask's doInBackground method, i always get an null bmp:

```
private final class ShowCoverTask extends AsyncTask<CoverParams, Void, WeakReference<Bitmap>> {


    @Override
    protected WeakReference<Bitmap> doInBackground(CoverParams... params) {
        final CoverParams coverParams = params[0];
        if (coverParams == null || !coverParams.available() || isCancelled()) return null;
        try {
            final MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(coverParams.mContext, coverParams.mUri);
            final Bitmap bmp = mmr.getFrameAtTime(coverParams.mPositon, OPTION_CLOSEST);
            mmr.release();
            if (bmp == null) return null;
            return new WeakReference<Bitmap>(bmp);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(WeakReference<Bitmap> bitmapWeakReference) {
        if (bitmapWeakReference != null && bitmapWeakReference.get() != null && mImgCover != null) {
            mImgCover.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mImgCover.setImageBitmap(bitmapWeakReference.get());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this??